# AG Grid Filtering issue

Tags: reactjs, grid, microservices, ag

So we have applied floating filter in second column of ag grid in react by applying the properties: floatingFilter:true,
filter:"agMultiColumnFilter",
Now while we are searching or filtering in second column the data in first column is not visible,We know its happening due to agGroupCellRenderer,since its grouping the columns.
Normal Scenario without filtering:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rb34.png)
Scenario for which its working :the data in first column is visible if it is parent node but child node its not visible it is coming as blank.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBoPU.png)
scenario which is not working:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiYUb.png)

like we r not able to find the solution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.